# Custom website scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar, parallax

I do not like the look of my browser's scrollbars on [my website](http://30sqfthouse.com/). To combat this, I had two ideas:

1. Get rid of the scrollbars.
2. Replace the default scrollbar with a custom one.

I am aware that I can use css to style the scrollbar, or hide it in webkit browsers, but I would like a more cross-browser solution. I think if I chose to hide the scrollbar, it would not affect the user experience, because of my navigation.

I have looked at several solutions ([such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll)) which use a system of wrappers and css to hide the scrollbar and put it off the canvas.  These do not work for me, because they interfere with the [parallax.js](http://pixelcog.github.io/parallax.js/) and bootstrap affix/scrollspy navbar that my site is running. I think this is because both scripts depend on the `body` element, and not a main wrapper, scrolling.

I have also looked into a jquery plugin to change the look of my scrollbar, specifically the [malihu custom scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/).  When I tried this, the scrollbar worked wonderfully, but the parallax and my scrollspy/affix navbar stopped working, for the same reasons above.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

To hide the scrollbar you could use this css:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

And [this](https://plugins.jquery.com/custom-scrollbar/) could give you the custom scrollbar you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that but I do not want to loose scrolling functionality.

Comment: You are not forced to lose scrolling functionality if you recreate the same behaviour with javascript. Although you will be forced to use javascript, obviously, don't know if that is a problem.

Comment: javascript isn't a problem, I am pretty sure that I will have to use it to get what I want.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure that removing your scrollbar is the best idea. When I bring down your menu it covers part of the content (for example, most of 'A New Plan' is covered) and it's a little annoying to constantly open the menu, close it to view the page, and open it back up again to go to the next page. Also for your 'whats on my mind' section, there are about 5 posts that I would have to scroll down in order to see (not to mention the footer), and there isn't any way to do that without a scroll bar.

Comment: There are ways of doing it by using javascript/jquery.